# M1 Mac: MongoServerSelectionError with Certificate when trying to connect to Mongo Cluster

Tags: mongodb, apple-m1, atlas

> MongoServerSelectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: ac-u3ijckb-shard-00-00.oide3ar.mongodb.net. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.mongodb.net, DNS:mongodb.net. It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your Network Access List allows connections from your IP.

When running the connection string I wasn't able to get past the error even with alt IPs.

I found out it has to do with the M1 chip and if anyone runs in to this bug my solution was to run --

`arch -arm64 brew install mongosh`

to install locally

and then run the copied connection string from Atlas database shell setup.

The solution seems very simple, yet, there wasn't much to find when searching the error through google or any of Atlas' previous debug threads.

Comment: you should take your solution out of the question and post it as an answer to your problem